# Replace a string in a text file using a shell script not working properly

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, quoting

I have a text file containing this:

```
0 0 -1 0
1 0 0 0
0 -1 0 0
1.5 0.0 1.0 1
```

and I want to replace the `1.0` to `2.0` so that it becomes:

```
0 0 -1 0
1 0 0 0
0 -1 0 0
1.5 0.0 2.0 1
```

so I use this command:

```
sed -i 's/'1.0'/'2.0'/g' /home/user1/file1.txt
```

or this:

```
sed -i 's/1.0/2.0/g' /home/user1/file1.txt
```

but this is the result that appears and I don't know how to fix this:

```
0 0 -2.0
2.0 0 0
0 -2.0 0
1.5 0.0 2.0 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape dot in search pattern:

```
sed -i 's/1\.0/2.0/g' /home/user1/file1.txt
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! what if `1.0` and `2.0` were saved in variables `$i` and `$j`? where `i` has the value `1.0` and `j` has the value `2.0`

Comment: You should save `1.0` as `1\.0`.

Comment: so is there any simple easy way to do that? because this code is in a loop and this value `1.0` changes from time to time and I don't want to save in the `file1.txt` as `1\.0` as this will affect the rest of the script.